# Deploy lambda with serverless framework not working with 2 seperate functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy a lambda function (lambda-1) with the serverless framework, which should have a s3 create event as trigger. Beside the lambda function to deploy exists a second lambda function (lambda-2) with a different name, which have nothing to do with each other. But also with a s3-trigger. Both functions using different Buckets. Every time I try to deploy lambda-1 it says the following:

```
CREATE_FAILED: CustomDashresourceDashexistingDashs3LambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
<prefix-of-both-lambdas>-custom-resource-existing-s3 already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:xxx:stack/<prefix-lambda-2>-<lambda-2-name>/xxxsome-uuidxxxx
View the full error: https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=eu-central-1#/stack/detail?stackId=arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aeu-central-1%......
1 deprecation found: run 'serverless doctor' for more details
```

config of lambda-1:

```
functions:
  lambda-1:
    handler: src/lambda_handler.main
    environment:
      ENV: ${opt:stage}
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${ssm:/panda/${opt:stage}/strings/lambda-1-bucket}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: <s3-prefix>/
            - suffix: .csv
          existing: true
          forceDeploy: true
resources:
  Outputs:
    ServerlessDeploymentBucketName:
      Export:
        Name: "${self:service}-${opt:stage}-${self:custom.serverless-aws-resource-names.variables.lambdaFunctionName}-sls-dpl"
    PythonRequirementsLambdaLayerHash:
      Export:
        Name: "${self:service}-${opt:stage}-${self:custom.serverless-aws-resource-names.variables.lambdaFunctionName}-requirements-LayerHash"
    PythonRequirementsLambdaLayerQualifiedArn:
      Export:
        Name: "${self:service}-${opt:stage}-${self:custom.serverless-aws-resource-names.variables.lambdaFunctionName}-requirements-LayerQualifiedArn"
    PythonRequirementsLambdaLayerS3Key:
      Export:
        Name: "${self:service}-${opt:stage}-${self:custom.serverless-aws-resource-names.variables.lambdaFunctionName}-requirements-LayerS3Key"
```

config of lambda-2:

```
functions:
  lambda-2:
    package:
      artifact: ${env:MVN_ARTIFACT_RELATIVE_PATH}
    handler: lambda_handler.Handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${ssm:/panda/${opt:stage}/strings/lambda-2-bucket}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - suffix: .xlsx
          existing: true
    logSubscription: true
    memorySize: 512
    timeout: 120

resources:
  Outputs:
    ServerlessDeploymentBucketName:
      Export:
        Name: "sls-${self:service}-${opt:stage}-${self:custom.serverless-aws-resource-names.variables.lambdaFunctionName}-ServerlessDeploymentBucketName"
```

When I delete both CloudFormation Stacks It is possible to deploy one of the lambdas but than the other one will fail. Also I didnt defined this ressource in the serverless.yml both s3-trigger-buckets are named different than than:
`<prefix-of-both-lambdas>-custom-resource-existing-s3`

[image: This ist the log of the CloudFormation Stack]

Comment: The code you provided only has 1 Lambda function defined. Please update it to include both. Also, check the CloudWatch log the error is pointing to and post relevant information.

Comment: I have added the lambda-2 config and also the log of the CloudFormation Stack

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the CloudFormation error, it looks like there is a pre-existing (or once existing) stack that was spun up with the same Lambda name at some point on your account.

The easiest way to fix this is to completely delete the resource in question,in this case the S3 bucket which is causing the conflict, and redeploy.

The reason it's failing to deploy `lambda-2` even though its `lambda-1` which has the conflict is that CloudFormation stacks require all resources to be able to be stood up else it will initiate a rollback process to reverse the operation.